# What is "Multi-Protocol Unified Hello" and what are the impacts of disabling/enabling it?

Tags: tls, windows

[This article](http://www.hass.de/content/setup-your-iis-ssl-perfect-forward-secrecy-and-tls-12) describes how to disable old versions of TLS, but in addition to doing so, "Multi-Protocol Unified Hello" is also disabled.

```
# Disable Multi-Protocol Unified Hello
md 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\Multi-Protocol Unified Hello\Server' -Force
New-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\Multi-Protocol Unified Hello\Server' -name Enabled -value 0 -PropertyType 'DWord' -Force
```

I searched for that term, and didn't see anything besides other registry edits that disable this.

What is the Multi-Protocol Hello, and why/when should someone disable/enable it?

Answer (score 3):

Not certain, but given context and MS penchant for bland names, it *could* be SSLv2/later compability.

When SSLv3 came out (long ago) it used a different message format than SSLv2, and sending a v3 ClientHello to a v2 server wouldn't work at all. Instead it was common practice to send a v2 *format* ClientHello containing flags indicating the client would prefer v3 protocol and ciphers. A v3-capable server could respond with v3 ServerHello and then v3 would proceed; a v2-only server would ignore the v3 flags, respond in v2 and v2 would proceed. TLS 1, 1.1 and 1.2 (internally numbered as SSL 3.1, 3.2, 3.3) kept the message format close enough this continued to work, mostly, as well as negotiating among the v3 and later protocols. OpenSSL called this 'SSLv23 method' and it remained the default until about 2 years ago when they switched to v3-and-up-only; Java called it 'SSLv2Hello' but wouldn't actually accept selection of v2.

Using SSLv2 has been a bad choice for a long time, and RFC 6176 in 2011 finally officially 'prohibited' it, but some (much?) software still supports it out of a combination of let-sleeping-dogs-lie and just-in-case-you-never-know, and I'd bet that includes SCHANNEL, so taking steps to disable those remnants of v2 is probably a Good Thing.

Comment: +1 likely to be the case. Found this [MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/55bb474d-3770-4037-8798-81b2fedf578a#id5): "Windows accepts a unified format Client Hello message even when SSL version 2 is disabled."